# Writing multiple for-loops (including one similar to the sum() function) in a pythonic way

Tags: python, loops, iteration, list-comprehension, networkx

I'm writing different basic algorithms to practice writing code in a pythonic manner. Below is a function that produces a basic pagerank score at step *k* for a given graph *G*:

```
import networkx as nx

def basic_pagerank(G,k):
    
    G_nodes = [node for node in G.nodes()]
    lenG = len(G_nodes)
    old_score = [1/lenG]*lenG
    new_score = [0]*lenG
    
    for i in range(0,k):
        for node in G_nodes:
            s_lst = [s for s in G.successors(node)]
            len_s_lst = len(s_lst)
            if len_s_lst != 0:
                for s in s_lst:
                    s_i = G_nodes.index(s)
                    node_i = G_nodes.index(node)
                    new_score[s_i] = new_score[s_i] + old_score[node_i]/len_s_lst                
        old_score = new_score
        new_score = [0]*lenG
    
    return  dict(zip(G_nodes, old_score))
```

So for example, for the following  graph:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('B','C'),('B','D'),('C','B'),('D','A'),('D','C'),('D','E'),('E','A')])
basic_pagerank(G, 2)
```

the output is `{'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.43, 'C': 0.23, 'D': 0.2, 'E': 0.03}`.

I'm having the most trouble expressing the innermost for-loop in a pythonic way. If I can do that, I think I can write the rest using list comprehension. So essentially, my question is, is there a way to write the innermost for-loop in a pythonic way?

Comment: You don't need the check `if len_s_lst != 0:` as if `s_lst` is empty the following for loop will not do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```py
def basic_pagerank(G,k):
    
    G_nodes = list(G.nodes())
    lenG = len(G_nodes)
    old_score = {n: 1/lenG for n in G_nodes}
    new_score = {n: 0 for n in G_nodes}
    
    for i in range(0,k):
        for node in G_nodes:
            s_list = list(G.successors(node))
            len_s_lst = len(s_list)
            s_score = {s: new_score[s] + old_score[node]/len_s_lst for s in s_list}
            new_score.update(s_score)
        old_score = new_score
        new_score = {n: 0 for n in G_nodes}
    
    return old_score
```